# How to Resizable column in pivot table in ZK

Tags: java, pivot-table, zk

I have pivot table with large content . Right now I am facing problem of column size.

If there are large content in database at that time some contents are not displayed .

Is there any property to make ZK pivottable column resizable .

Please check below image for more clear idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the following Javascript to resize it.
For example,

```
zk.Widget.$(jq('@pivottable')).$n('dataTitle').style.width = '600px';
```

Comment: No . I want to do scrollable . if my content is large than 600 px ? then what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

See ZK pivoty tabel live demo

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/application/pivottable

may be you found your solution